# Spring setter dependency injection and immutable object

Tags: java, spring

We know that spring team suggests using setter injection over field injection:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#d0e2778

Which is what also needed to do unit testing by injecting mock.

However, one thing really is bothering me is that as the spring beans are singletons, so if in some part of the code, the singleton beans are reconfigured by injecting different dependency using the setter methods, then other parts of the code are going to be affected which might be unwanted. For instance, in some part of the code a particular clock instance is injected but may be that particular kind of clock is undesirable in other parts of the code.

So it looks like setter injection leaves some door open for risky business. At the same time we need to a mechanism to inject some mock during testing. How can we strike a balance?

Besides as we know that mutable objects are undesirable:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15

Then is it not bad to use setter methods available for singleton beans?

Comment: I imagine if you were concerned you could use the `afterPropertiesSet` method to set a flag preventing further calls to setters.

Comment: Use constructor injection?

Comment: I can use afterPropertiesSet or constructor injection. But then my original problem of being able to inject Mock during each test would not be solved.

Comment: Why wouldn't the problem of injecting a mock during test would be solved? Construct a new object using the mock, problem solved...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit confusing here, on one hand you say:

> unit testing by injecting mock

Here you could use use Mockito or a standard JUnit test to create your instance and inject the appropriate dependencies.

But then you go on to say:

> other parts of the code are going to be affected which might be unwanted

Not quite unit testing, but you can use Spring Test support with [`@DirtiesContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html) to ensure that if you change the dependencies in one test, then the context will get reloaded for the next test.

Should you really need to change an instance field but don't have a setter, as a last resort you can still use [`ReflectionTestUtils`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html) to update the field during the test.

Comment: That is also confused me - that was the reason for asking this question. As  spring beans are meant to be singleton then we are not supposed to use the setter injection because that will mess the whole singleton mechanism at the same time we need to insert mocks. The spring test you mention, I already use this - for integration testing (remember Robert C Martin among others has defined unit testing is something without any explicit dependency using mocks).

Comment: This is my question - why does Spring creates the singleton beans and at the same time recommends setter method which is seemingly very dangerous.

Comment: The [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-setter-injection) is slightly different now: _The Spring team generally advocates constructor injection as it enables one to implement application components as immutable objects and to ensure that required dependencies are not null. Furthermore constructor-injected components are always returned to client (calling) code in a fully initialized state._

Comment: On setter injection: _Setter injection should primarily only be used for optional dependencies that can be assigned reasonable default values within the class. Otherwise, not-null checks must be performed everywhere the code uses the dependency. One benefit of setter injection is that setter methods make objects of that class amenable to reconfiguration or re-injection later._